# How to Create a Meteor App From Branch

Tags: git, github, meteor, branch, meteorite

I'm using [Meteorite](https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite) and saw the repo readme mention :

```
mrt create my-app --branch devel
```

However, I'm getting an error when doing such. Meteor saying that --branch are not a recognize command.

More importantly, how can you create the app using specific branch? Or can I go into smart.lock and put Meteor's git with the branch that I want?

I know that I can use a specific release, but I would love to know how can I use a specific branch instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed the `meteor` entry in my `smart.json` (not `smart.lock`) file to read:

```
{
  "meteor": {
    "git": "https://github.com/meteor/meteor.git",
    "branch": "shark"
  },
  "packages": {
    ...
   }
}
```

Instead of `branch` field, you can also use `tag` to point to a particular release.

Answer (score 1):

As musically_ut stated, you can do the following in your smart.json file:

```
{
  "meteor": {
    "git": "https://github.com/meteor/meteor.git",
    "branch": "shark"
  },
  "packages": {
    ...
  } 
}
```

However, you will not be able to benefit from this change when running your app unless you launch your app by running 'mrt' or 'mrt run' from your app directory (rather than running 'meteor' or 'meteor run'). This had me stumped for quite a while so I thought I would add this here for others traveling down this same path. Thanks to Tom Coleman on meteor-core for the pointer!